# How to fetch data from Python function to JavaScript | Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Here, I am trying to get data("Okay, we'll see.") from `get_bot_response` function. But every time when I call it from JavaScript, it shows `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Here is how I tried,

Views.py

```
def get_bot_response(request):
    userText = request.GET.get('msg')
    return "Okay, we\'ll see."
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('get/', views.get_bot_response, name='get'),
]
```

In template script

```
function botResponse(rawText) {
        // Bot Response
        $.get("/get", { msg: rawText }).done(function (data) {
            const msgText = data;
            appendMessage("", "msgText");

        });

    }
```

As well as in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/get/` it shows **Error:** `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 0):

You must return a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) (or a subclass thereof) from your views. You cannot just return a string

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_bot_response(request):
    userText = request.GET.get('msg')
    return HttpResponse("Okay, we\'ll see.")
```